# Crear subconsultas en eloquent laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy realizando un proyecto en laravel de una escuela online en el cual tengo que crear un reporte mensual. El problema es que tengo que unir 5 tablas diferentes

- Usuarios (es esta tabla en donde estan los datos generales)
- Materias (todas las materias disponibles en la plataforma)
- Cursos (todos los cursos con los que cuenta la materia)
- compra cursos (todos los cursos comprados por un usuario)
- ganancias (las ganancias que obtienen los maestros por sus cursos)

tengo esta consulta.

```
$data= DB::table('ganancias')->select('users.*','datos_bancos.*' ,   'materias.*',
                                        DB::raw('SUM(ganancias.monto) as total '))
                            ->where('ganancias.id_user_fk', '!=', 1)
                            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ganancias.id_user_fk')
                            ->join('datos_bancos', 'users.id', '=', 'datos_bancos.id_user_fk')
                            ->join('compra_cursos', 'compra_cursos.id_compra_cursos', '=', 'ganancias.id_compra_cursos_fk')
                            ->join('cursos', 'cursos.id_curso', '=', 'compra_cursos.id_curso_fk')
                            ->join('materias', 'materias.id_materia', '=', 'cursos.id_materia_fk')
                            ->groupBy('id','id_DatosBancos','id_materia')
                            ->get();
```

Tengo dos tipos de ganancias (por grupo y por afiliado) el problema es que me saca la suma de manera general y lo que busco es que me pueda dar el desglosado de cuento fue por grupo y cuento fue por afiliado.

Comment: Agrega una muestra de la salida que esperas obtener

Comment: Esto no es Eloquent amigo, estás utilizando el query builder de laravel. Da igual como lo hagas, al final llegas al mismo resultado, mas que nada por si te estás examinando de Eloquent o algo asi